# cnn package missing in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, package, conv-neural-network, convolution

My project is about Sign language recognition using convolution neural networks.
When I run, It prompts with 
**ModuleNotfound: error No module named 'cnn_utils**'

I am running with conda/jupyter notebook environment.
How can I import CNN utility packages in jupyter notebook?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have conda installed in `/opt/conda`.

Now we have two possibilities:

1. `cnn_utls` is a module you've written before and it is located in `/home/soban/my/modules/are/here/cnn_utils`. In such a case you have to add the location of the folder containing this module to `sys.path` (i.e. list of paths where Python looks for modules). Try paste it in your notebook:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/soban/my/modules/are/here")
import cnn_utils
```

2. `cnn_utils` is a package from pip. This probably means you were using different installation of Python for developing your code before and different for Jupyter. Simply run `/opt/conda/bin/pip install cnn_utils`.

Also consider removing tags like "conv-neural-network" because your problem has nothing to do with neural nets :)

Comment: sir am using windows10 and i couldn't find any packages underneath the directory c:/python36/ or c:/users/mypc/.conda/ or c:/users/mypc/.anaconda